# Is there any problem I should watch out for in running the Nix package manager alongside Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I'm starting on a fresh macOS install and so far only have Nix installed. Can Homebrew coexist well with it or do I have to pick one and stick with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience so far is that yes, you can run both. I also naïvely installed `nix` thinking I would use that instead of `homebrew`, but I soon ran into packages that were only found in `homebrew`. So I installed both and never had any conflicts. And there should be none, as they simply overlay scopes sequentially. If you evaluate `nix` after `homebrew` in your path, it will take precedence, and vice-versa. Their stores are completely separate.

However if you want to be *super clean*, you can do this:

```
$ <install homebrew>
$ brew tap caskroom/cask
$ brew cask install nix
```

Yes, `nix` is currently just another package within `cask`! Isn't that amazing?

Comment: Sadly the `nix` homebrew cask was removed soon after this was posted: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/47423